# awk to update filename in directory

Tags: regex, shell, awk, rename, file-rename

In the below I am trying to use `awk` to change part of a pair of filenames (between the hyphen and underscore) in a directory with a value stored in a variable. The below does execute but the filenames do not change. Thank you :).

**variable**

```
id=aaaaa
```

**files in directory**

```
00-0000-xxx-y-zzz_x1_y.txt
00-0000-xxx-y-zzz_x2_y.txt
```

**desired**

```
00-0000-xxx-y-aaaaa_x1_y.txt
00-0000-xxx-y-aaaaa_x2_y.txt
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'-' var=$id'{sub("$5","var")}1' *.txt
```

Comment: awk is changing file content not the file name itself. You will need to use `rename` perl utility

Comment: A shell is a tool to manipulate (create, destroy, **rename**, etc.) files and processes. Awk is a tool to manipulate text. You're trying to use the wrong tool for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is changing file content, not the file name itself.

Instead of awk, you may use `rename` perl utility like this:

```sh
id='aaaaa'
rename -n "s/^(.*)-[^_]+_/\$1-${id}_/" *.txt

'00-0000-xxx-y-zzz_x1_y.txt' would be renamed to '00-0000-xxx-y-aaaaa_x1_y.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(with pure bash solution), following will go through all `.txt` files and will print rename commands only on terminal. In case you are happy with results shown on terminal then append  `| bash` to the solution. Note, please set `id=aaaaa` before running following commands.

```
for file in *.txt
do
   echo "mv $file ${file%-*}-${id}_${file#*_}"
done
```

---

---

Once you are happy with results above then run following to actually rename files to new file.

```
for file in *.txt
do
   echo "mv $file ${file%-*}-${id}_${file#*_}"
done | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have awk create bash commands for you and then pipe the output of awk to bash.

```
ls *.txt | awk -F'[_-]' -vvar=$id '{f=$0 ; sub($5,var); print "mv", f, $0 } ' | bash
```

There were a number of fundamental issues.

1. By passing *.txt to awk - awk will open each .txt file in your directory line by line.  Rather, you wanted to just process the directory listing (so I added ls *.txt ).
2. The variable var must be set with the -v option of awk.
3. You didn't need to quote "$5" and "var".   I suspect you pasted some old code into your question since you got it working.
4. The field separator of - is insufficient.  You'll lose the '_x1_y.txt' and '_x2_y.txt' portions of your file names.  I added underscore as an additional field delimiter.

As a debugging tip, you can review what awk is going to do before taking any action:

```
$ ls *.txt | awk -F'[_-]' -vvar=$id '{f=$0 ; sub($5,var); print "mv", f, $0 } '
mv 00-0000-xxx-y-zzz_x1_y.txt 00-0000-xxx-y-aaaaa_x1_y.txt
mv 00-0000-xxx-y-zzz_x2_y.txt 00-0000-xxx-y-aaaaa_x2_y.txt
```

If the above looks good, just pipe the output to bash (as in the first code I provided ).